# Does the compiler actually use my "omp declare simd" functions?

Tags: c++, openmp, simd

Have a look at [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/TVLgSC) I constructed for a 4D dot product:

```
#pragma omp declare simd
double dot(double x0, double y0, double z0, double w0, double x1, double y1, double z1, double w1)
{
    return x0 * x1 + y0 * y1 + z0 * z1 + w0 * w1;
}

#define SIMD 4

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x[SIMD];
    double y[SIMD];
    double z[SIMD];
    double w[SIMD];

    double r[SIMD];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIMD; i++)
    {
        x[i] = y[i] = z[i] = 1;
        w[i] = 0;
    }

#pragma omp simd
    for (int i = 0; i < SIMD; i++)
    {
        r[i] = dot(x[i], y[i], z[i], w[i], x[i], y[i], z[i], w[i]);
    }

    double s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIMD; i++)
    {
        s += r[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

In the compiler output you can see that it generates a few functions called `_XXXXXXvvvvvvvv_dot`. I assume that these are the functions used for different lengths of input for the `dot` function, or at least that is what they are supposed to be. However, these function do not seem to be actually used by the compiler. Line 94 of the output reads `call dot(…)`. Does that call one of these functions? What do I have to do to use them?

Comment: How did you compile the code? Did you make sure to compile against your actual CPU capabilities (or a higher than default set of capabilities anyway), e.g. with `-march=native` on GCC or the like?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I actually don't know how godbolt handles this...

Comment: Godbolt doesn't add any optimization args to your command line, only `-g` to get source <-> asm mapping metadata.  The GCC default is `-O0` - anti-optimize for debugging, so of course the code is total garbage and not actually auto-vectorized (no `addpd` or `mulpd` instructions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't try to call the SIMD versions manually: let the compiler do that from a loop that it's auto-vectorizing.**

You didn't enable optimization so GCC doesn't auto-vectorize your loops.  Thus it only calls the scalar version of the function.

The GCC default is `-O0` - anti-optimize for debugging, so of course the code is total garbage and not actually auto-vectorized (no `addpd` or `mulpd` instructions).

**Enable optimization with `-O3`**.  GCC will simply inline the calls when it can see the definition.  The `#pragma omp declare simd` thing lets the compiler emit calls to vectorized versions of the function even if it *can't* see the definition.  (Or for larger functions that it chooses not to inline.)

---

You can use `__attribute__((noinline))` on `dot` to see how it works even for your small function:

[On Godbolt with GCC9.1 `-O3 -fopenmp`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMAB2JNgAWyYBqVCvnqsyZsUzrBeFeg4AGAIIB9G0wIFieAEYiCmO1Bao8LBn6YAJRBllbooi4MRhEEEBEiUUYAHhakupHR6gCeaRmJWQBeeQlJ6gDuJZkp9Pll2bWlRY3VFbSh1hwA7HzW6v3qhgRiLOqp6gBUY7Tq/DkWkzkzc8WLhcu8FQtT5bQcsr1W3QAiYWdcslgAZoHqAMoAkgCyx%2BoALGfWfgTqan4Q33UTGIwGQ6WQCGBkwmwOAADcOkcemEBnUsskOABWHiPF5Y04HFEDJpGbJYnHPU6YgmHVEk9SFcm4qk0on9enlJmU/H7Q5stFGYhcvHU3mfKyoq4kdQAlg/PCzWSvCy89QK/YAYXu3IOav4/ERqO6tNRAwx2Lw%2BMVrzJFqt%2B1ejLt1Ot6j2hL6pv6nOdrwd6hVHolAxO4rkimUak02mMpnMnv6UuIMsB6qVAdVaa1zMz%2Bt4hpDyITpqFvtdsQg5p4lup6Vt1fx6SdDdrFXJNeO6SrHbr7cbDL7rZ9LeOoSDRq6p06xfpgldgZNielsvl88ziuzOp4et4Bv5xv5qLn%2BvTpZHYuLoeLQxGxgvSOOUiCjGkmKkpBY0gs79Q0g1ee3YQxAkWYLlod8CC/J9nwAaxAN4AA4ADougsWQENkABOTEADZsK6PD6AYaQ3nfT8pG/Uhfykd9BBANJIIop9SDgWAkDQbQ8GiMgKAgDj5C4zBiBAYBMPoG4GA8Yg6IgFwoNIFw/GBbJpHA0gOJUTA5QAeX8FSmNILA1DYaJ5PwQxkAIPA4UwOiDMwZJMGQdxJCkNTvkwYiDICFwlGIbINQwVy1KcUxVOY5g2BQADGFcOjIGfVB5Cs1AWDsgBaKV5C0mN0u02RaNEcRJHaF8pDfD95Oo5IEJw9KcLedRQWQdRMKQmYIFwQhpTkWpAs47jQNkdp1H/XdeAgqCQlIBBMCYLBhIgWCQExWgkK4TCcNoHCLDeWRdouCwELK0jKoM6jaPo0hGO/aavK4MiqukSamOmmzpLwVL4KAA%3D%3D%3D), with that change:

```
# gcc9.1 -O3 -fopenmp
main:
        sub     rsp, 40
        movapd  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]     # {1, 1}
        pxor    xmm7, xmm7                      # {0, 0}
        movapd  xmm3, xmm7
        movapd  xmm6, xmm0                      # duplicate the 1,1 vector for several args
        movapd  xmm5, xmm0
        movapd  xmm4, xmm0
        movapd  xmm2, xmm0
        movapd  xmm1, xmm0
        call    _ZGVbN2vvvvvvvv_dot(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0        # store to the stack
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+16], xmm0     # twice
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0                     # 0.0
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp]          # 0 + v[0]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]        # ... += v[1]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]       # stupid inefficient horizontal sum
        add     rsp, 40
        cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0              # truncate to integer as main's return value
        ret
```

With your tiny `#define SIMD 4`, `main` doesn't actually need to loop at all, just two 16-byte vectors is sufficient.  The arrays with compile-time-constant initializers get optimized away; GCC just materializes the constants into registers with `pxor`-zeroing for 0.0 and loading + copying from static constant data for `1.0`.

So anyway, there's only one call to a SIMD version of `dot()`, but this is it.  I think GCC knows that the same call will give the same result, which is why it calls once but stores the result twice.

IDK why GCC's OpenMP horizontal sum is so dumb.  Obviously it would be better to `addpd xmm0,xmm0` instead of storing it twice, and a shuffle could avoid a store/reload.  Also using an `addsd` to do `0.0 + x` is pointless; just use the low element of the register that you stored from.

---

The scalar version of `dot()` has the usual C++ name mangling for a function.  The other versions have special name-mangling conventions, maybe specific to GCC's OpenMP, IDK.

---

Interestingly, gcc makes a few different versions of `dot`, including an AVX version using YMM registers.  And some that spill to the stack and use scalar math in a loop; IDK why those exist.

So I guess that means that even if you compile this source file without `-march=skylake-avx512`, another loop that *is* compiled that way can still emit a call to `_ZGVeN8vvvvvvvv_dot` and get the AVX512 definition:

```
_ZGVeN8vvvvvvvv_dot(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
        vmulpd  zmm1, zmm1, zmm5
        vfmadd132pd     zmm0, zmm1, zmm4
        vfmadd231pd     zmm0, zmm2, zmm6
        vfmadd231pd     zmm0, zmm3, zmm7
```

Strangely I don't see an AVX+FMA definition that uses FMA on YMM regs, only SSE2 and AVX definitions that use vmulpd / vaddpd.

Comment: GCC needs `-mprefer-vector-width=512` to use YMM registers. Clang and ICC don’t, but still support it.